# List of Apache RPM directories

Tags: linux, apache, rpm

Can someone please list out the directories where the Apache RPM install files.
I searched over Internet but was not able to find any proper solution

Comment: If you're lazy like me, you can navigate into RPMs and their content.cpio using `mc` (Midnight Commander). That won't catch files generated by install scripts, though.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **query files list** option of `rpm` command to find out the directory.

If you have installed the package

```
rpm -ql <package-name>
```

and if you have the rpm file

```
rpm -qlp <package-name>.rpm
```

You will get something like this(the sample is for `httpd`)

```
/etc/httpd
/etc/httpd/conf
/etc/httpd/conf.d
/etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf
/etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-dav.conf
/etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-default.conf
/etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-info.conf
/etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-languages.conf
//
//Output truncated
```

The sample output shows `/etc/httpd` is a folder that `httpd` creates/installs to

Answer (score 0):

Add the very verbose flag to the rpm command line to see all it does. E.g.:

```
rpm -Ivv <packagefile.rpm>
```

Comment: getting this output after executing the above command.rpm: -Ivvv: unknown option

Comment: sorry, that should have been just two 'v's. Have changed the answer now. And you should check out the man page for rpm (http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/rpm.8.html) for more details.